# Get last link between two tables in a table link which save action using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables : persons and musics. I have a N to N connection between them. So I need an intermediate table between them. I also want to save the evolution of the connection between them, so I decide that the intermediate table will save actions (start to listen the music, stop to listen the music )

For example :

```
IdPerson | IdMusic  | Start    | DateTime
1        | 1        | true     | 10/01/2014
1        | 2        | true     | 10/01/2014
1        | 2        | false    | 11/01/2014
2        | 1        | true     | 11/01/2014
1        | 2        | true     | 12/01/2014
```

This table means that the person 1 start to listen music 1 and 2 the 10th, it stop the music 2 the 11th and restart the music 2 on the 12th. The person 2 start the music 1 the 11th.

In this table, (IdPerson,IdMusic,Date) is unique.

How can I obtain the musics listen by a person at a given date using SQL ?

I think, we need first to use `WHERE IdPerson=IdgivenPerson ORDER BY date` but after I don't now how to do the rest in SQL.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server, I am also using C#

Comment: @EliottRoynette On your question it is not clear that you are using datetime for that date column. So I will give you this piece of advise. Turn that date on date time, because you are talking about music and must probably you will have a person that start to listen a music and stop it at the same date with a difference of few minutes.

Comment: @Campos Yes i am using a dateTime, it is just for the example in didn't want to put hours, minutes, ect.. My bad, I correct it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```
select c.idMusic
from Connections c 
where c.IdPerson = IdgivenPerson and
      c.datetime <= GivenDate
group by c.idMusic
having sum(case when start = 'true' then 1
                when start = 'false' then -1
           end) > 0;
```

It counts the number of starts and stops before the date.  When there are more starts than stops, then the id for the music is returned.

EDIT:

If you just want the last action:

```
select c.*
from Connections c 
where c.IdPerson = IdgivenPerson and
      not exists (select 1
                  from Connections c2
                  where c2.IdPerson = c.IdgivenPerson and
                        c2.IdMusic = c.IdMusic and
                        c2.date > c.date and
                        c2.date <= GivenDate
                  );
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like a good idea even if I would prefer somthing which just take care about the last action for an person and a music. Because in this case if there is a mistake in the data before, everything will be wrong. (for example if it is click fast and there is no protection on the data entry, there can be twice true and every result are going to be wrong). But your idea is a good idea, and I keep it in mind :)

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what i was looking for but I feel like it miss something like `c2.date > c.date` in the 2nd WHERE and `c.date <= givenDate` in the first WHERE , doesn't it ?

Comment: @EliottRoynette . . . Good catch.  It was missing the second condition.